# How do I manage sessions in php by displaying different navigation bars depending on person logged in

Tags: php, html, session

I'm creating a website in php and HTML and for the pages I want it so that depending on the user ID logged in that the page will display the appropriate navigation menu for that user but I've tried searching the internet for an answer and come up short, I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
//start session 
session_start();
//if user ID equals 2 then the user is the admin so display admin navigation bar
if($_SESSION['userid'] = '2'){
include 'AdminNav.php';
//if user ID equals 1 then the user is not admin so display logged in navigation bar
}elseif($_SESSION['userid'] = '1'){
include 'LoggedInNav.php';
//user is not logged in display logged out navigation bar
}else{
include 'LoggedOutNav.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code above?

Comment: @sergChernata i put this code at the top of my website pages and i've set it so that if the user is the admin, then it will display the admin navigation bar at the top of the page, if not then it will display my user navigation bar which does not include a link to the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typos in conditional sections:

```
if($_SESSION['userid'] = '2'){
```

should be

```
if($_SESSION['userid'] == '2'){
```

Comment: Thank you so much i didnt know that was the issue i thought it was something bigger, its all working fine now :)